# If-else Statements using a csv file

Tags: r, shiny

I am having trouble using a csv file and integrating that into my code.

For example: Say I have a big dataset, let us name it data, with 1,000 rows of just random colors, column row named colors.

In addition I have another data set, let's name it `second`, with two columns: `If` and `Then`. Let's say that the If column contains a few random colors and `then` is a number.

I want the code to replace `data$colors` with the number in the `then` column.

Why does

```
ifelse(data$colors == second$If, data$colors == second$then, data$colors == data$colors)
```

not work?

Comment: Because you need `%in%` instead of `==`.  You could probably write `with(data, ifelse(colors %in% second$If, second$then, colors))`

Comment: Also, your code is nothing but tests with  `==`, which will always return TRUE of FALSE. It sounds to me like you should `merge` your `data` to `second` first, then write an `ifelse` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two reasons that  `ifelse(data$colors == second$If, data$colors == second$then, data$colors == data$colors)` doesn't "work". The inner reason is that the "==" function is not a test for set containment, but is rather a vectorized function that is probably not going to successful match up values in columns of two different dataframes. You probably do want to use `%in%` as was mentioned in Richard comment. But probably more importantly, you did not assign the value of the `ifelse` function to anything. (And ifelse does not do assignment within the consequent and alternate expressions.  R is a functional language. You really only do useful actions when you assign values to an object. You would instead do something like:

```
 data$colors[ data$colors %in% second$If] <-  second$then[ match( data$colors, second$If) ]
```

This will replace any value of `data$colors` with the value of `seconds$then` indexed by a vector of the position of the `data$colors`-value within the `second$If`-vector.

(At least that's what I think should happen. You provided no test data and many of us here think that is your responsibility, not ours. So this theory is untested for logical or syntactic errors on my part. Standard Warranty for Internet Advice: If it breaks, you get to keep all the pieces.)

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately due to work related matters, I was unable to provide a sample dataset. However I am receiving the error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" using your line of code. Any thoughts?

Comment: The claim of "work-related matters" preventing construction of an example is unconvincing. Change all the column names and fuzz all the data and then post it using `dput()`.